# Favicon routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon

I have added this to my application layout:

```
 <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.png' %>
```

Because I have my favicon icon under /assets/images.

However, I keep getting this error on my logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico")
```

It just stops if I add an empty favicon.ico under /public. But I don't get it, because I am not saying anywhere in my project to look for a favicon.ico

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.png', :type => ‘image/png’ %>
```

It will create link like

```
<link href="/assets/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon"  :type => ‘image/png’ />
```

Comment: also clear cache in your browser. Web browsers request favicon automatically from public location, changing the link as Johnny says might not help if browser cache will still point to the old location.

Comment: or add param to favicon link `<%= favicon_link_tag "/favicon.ico?1" %>` to trick the browser to load new icon.